# Xpath not returning the TEXT form the <p> tags in Scrapy Shell

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Link: https://www.softwareadvice.com/hr/zenefits-profile

I am trying to scrape the description from the above link. The `XPath` seems correct but it doesn't return me the value in `scrapy shell`. (Please see the screenshot below).
I tried all methods like `get()`, `getall()`, `extract()`, `extract_first()`, `extractall()` but I am getting an empity list. 
Kindly help me to identify the error. Thanks...

[Click to see the image (XPath)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwvFc.png)

[Click to see the image (Scrapy Shell)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwpZQ.png)

Comment: You XPath expression is correct. The website uses JavaScript so you need to load that. The best way to do it is to do pip install scrapy-splash. Use splash and the expression will work.

Comment: @dram95 it's not loading with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable JS you will not find that XPATH working.

That is how Scrapy loads the HTML, it loads only HTML and does not execute any JS/AJAX

Try this XPATH

```
response.xpath("/html/body/app-root/main/app-product/div[1]/app-product-detail/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/p//text()").getall()
```

Comment: thanks it worked but it's getting only the first <p> tag. How can I get all the <p> tage?